# Excel - The most spending occurred around this date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I feel like as a human I can understand this, but I can't figure out how to get it into an Excel formula.

Given the dates and amounts spent on those dates below, how can I find a date on which the most spending occurred around? Sort of like a "heat map."

```
Date        Spending
01/01/22    1000.00
02/02/22    523.25
04/01/22    2015.35
04/15/22    1258.62
04/18/22    3025.35
06/23/22    152.35
07/22/22    852.36
```

Looking at it, I can assume the majority of the total spending happened around 04/16/22 due to the three close April dates with higher amounts.

I can't figure out a formula to calculate that.

Comment: Start by figuring out how spending on one day influences the "heat" of the days around it and how far that influence extends. You could try adding all the spending 3 days before and after a date (7 days total). Maybe spending only influences adjacent days half as much so spending on day N influences N 100% but spending from N+1 only counts 50% towards N and N+2 is 25%, etc. We can't figure out for you what that scheme should be but, once you decide up on it, writing the formula should be much simpler.

Comment: why not 04/18/22?

Comment: OP wants to introduce the assumption that spending in days "near" to a day influence the answer. So while 18th is largest, there are also large values in 1st and 15th. In fact, since the sum of the 1st and 15th is larger than the value on the 18th, it might be said to drag the resulting date towards them.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description the result should be **4/18/2022**.

If my understanding is correct, try this formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(MAX($B$2:$B$8),$B$2:$B$8,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I think OP wants days to influence each other and to influence the date between them as well.